# MFC Background image issue

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I add a background image to my window, and other images do not appear.

The background image overlap other images

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/efb2z.png

how to fix ?

### Code

```
/* ENTER */
CPngImage imagea;
imagea.Load(IDB_PNG1);

image.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)imagea.Detach());

/*  PROGRESS BAR */
CPngImage imageaa;
imageaa.Load(IDB_PNG2);

image2.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)imageaa.Detach());

/* BACKGROUND */    
CPngImage imageaaa;
imageaaa.Load(IDB_PNG3);

image3.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)imageaaa.Detach());
```

> New poblem
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIurg.png

Comment: Do you draw the background image after everything else? Otherwise we need to see some code...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `MFC` But this seems like loading of images to me ( ? ) I'm more interested in the code where your draw `image`, `image2`, `image3`.

Comment: What do you mean by "background image"? Do you mean in the background behind data inside a view, or background behind MDI child windows, or ...?

Answer (score 1):

are you using the `SetWindowPos` function properly ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OnEraseBackground().

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make a background image:
- draw directly on the dialog in OnEraseBackground()
- put an image behind all other controls

There are some subtle pro and cons to each approach, but for most application both should work. It seems you're using the second method. What you need to do is make sure the background control is all the way at the bottom of the control stack (z-pos - use SetWindowPos() to send it to the background, or just create it before all others, but then you can't use the dialog editor) and also to make sure your background control has WS_CLIPSIBLINGS set.

Answer (score 0):

`CPngImage` supports the MFC framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.